# Import Cucumber with Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, cucumber, build.gradle, geb

I want to import `cucumber.api.java.en.*` into my groovy files, but `cucmber.api` will not be recognized as in my classpath. Thus every `@Given` or `@When` annotation is not recognized.

When I build with `./gradlew` cucumber the `.feature` file is found and missing snippets are shown in the console. What do I have to include in my `build.gradle` to add above import into my classpath?
My gradle version is 2.2 and the cucumber related parts of my build.gradle file look like this:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4'
}
test {

    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Share what IDE you are using. I have assumed IntelliJ IDEA in my response. But that is just an assumption.

Comment: Your assumption is correct :) I am using IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include `info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4` which is the jar containing the annotations you are missing. They are expected to be available in your test classpath.

To me, it sounds as an issue with your IDE.

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, try to re-import the project. Click on the two rotating arrows in your Gradle tab and refresh the project.